# Integrals can sometimes be computed through their saddle points. Are there examples of converse, when saddle points are found via integrals?

Tags: integration, asymptotics, nonlinear-optimization, integral-transforms, global-optimization

Under some reasonable assumptions integrals with large exponents can often be computed via saddle point approximations, e.g.
$$\int e^{-\lambda f(x)}\approx e^{-\lambda f(x_0)},\qquad \lambda\to\infty$$
where I assume that $x_0$ is a unique minimum of the function $f(x)$. These types of computations are omnipresent in physics, for example. I am interested if there are examples in the reverse direction, when finding the minimum of $f(x)$ directly is challenging, but computing something like
$$\frac{\int e^{-\lambda f(x)}x}{\int e^{-\lambda f(x)}}\approx x_0,\qquad \lambda\to\infty$$
is tractable and allows to locate the minimum. Perhaps generalization to many variables or functional integrals would be more appropriate.

I hope the question is meaningful despite the lack of precision and rigor. Any comments are welcome!

Comment: I don't think this "reverse engineering" will work; take the simple example $\int_{-1}^{1}e^{ix\sin\pi t}\,dt=2J_0(|x|)$, with saddle point at $t=1/2$. How would you recover that from an integral?

Comment: I didn't check carefully but it must be that (note additional $t$ in the numerator) $\int_{-1}^1 dt e^{i x \sin \pi t} t/\int_{-1}^1 dt e^{i x \sin \pi t}$ tends to $\frac12$ in the large $x$ limit. In this case of course one can find the saddle point directly. The procedure should always work (formally), my question is if there are any examples when this is useful.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I'm not sure why you say the integrals do not converge. Mathematica's `With[{x = 10}, NIntegrate[Exp[ x Sin[\[Pi] t]] t, {t, -1, 1}]/
 NIntegrate[Exp[ x Sin[\[Pi] t]], {t, -1, 1}]]` gives me `0.499989`.

Comment: I meant no convergence in the limit $x\rightarrow\infty$; I worked it out a bit more in the answer box, that seemed easier than continuing as comments.

Comment: This trick is common in machine learning, where $\frac{\int e^{\lambda f(x)} x}{\int e^{\lambda f(x)}}$ is known as the "softmax" function, typically in the context where the integrals are finite sums. These are often easier to compute numerically because for finite $\lambda$ the softmax function is differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but continuing the discussion in the comment box is a bit cumbersome. The point I want to make is to see if this would work for a simple test case, $f(t)=ix\sin\pi t$, with saddle point at $t=1/2$. So the question is whether we can "reverse engineer" this value of $t$ from integrals of the form $\int e^{ix\sin\pi t}dt$. The OP suggest to look at the ratio
$$I(x)=\frac{\int_{-1}^1 e^{ix\sin\pi t}t\,dt}{i\int_{-1}^1 e^{ix\sin\pi t}\,dt}=\frac{1}{J_0(|x|)}\int_{0}^1 \sin(x\sin\pi t)\,t\,dt.$$
Can we somehow recover the value $t=1/2$ from the large-$x$ behaviour of $I(x)$?

From the plot of $I(x)$ it seems that this function does not converge to a definite limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

[image]

Comment: Replacing $i x$ by $x$ seems to fix the issue.

Comment: very good, indeed $I(-ix)\rightarrow 1/2$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$, I'm just wondering how we would know the replacement $x\mapsto ix$ if all information we had came to us via integrals, but this may well be the way to go.

Comment: Well for real exponent the integral clearly localizes near the minimum. For complex exponent, as in you original computation, both critical points $t=\pm\frac12$ probably contribute and the analysis is more involved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very particular instance of what's known as [moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem), or sometimes "inverse moment problem". One has an unknown measure $\mu$ in some space of measures, and one tries to reconstruct $\mu$ from knowlegde of $\mu_k:=\int f_k(x) d\mu(x)$, $k=0,1,\dots$, for a well-behaved sequence of functions $f_k$.

This readily generalises to several dimensions.

Comment: I think the difference with my question is that I assume that the measure $\mu$ is known, but it's difficult to find its critical points directly.

Comment: You are, essentially, trying to find the best Dirac measure appoximating your measure.

Comment: OK, but I do not assume that the moments are given. Rather, I'm interested to look at the situation when the measure is known explicitly, it's critical points are hard to find, but the moments can still be computed.

Comment: all the moments are seldom known in such a settting. Sometimes one can say something about a moment generating function though, and derive something from the latter.